# Any pugilist worth his salt knows when someone's on the ropes that's when you throw a combination to the gut and a left hook to the jaw

Tags: house-of-cards

I heard this line said by Frank Underwoord in season 2 episode 5,
"**Any pugilist worth his salt knows when someone's on the ropes, that's when you throw a combination to the gut and a left hook to the jaw.**"

I am not a native english speaker. I could not understand what he means in this sentence. 
Can someone help?

Comment: This isn't on topic here. I don't even know if it's a good fit on https://ELL.StackExchange.com/ , so before posting it there, please [follow the tour](https://ELL.StackExchange.com/tour) and read ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://ELL.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask), ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://ELL.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://ELL.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: I'd usually be of the opinion that a comprehension question would be off-topic; just in this case I felt the underlying meaning requires knowledge of not just the language used & the sport involved, but how it relates to Underwood's character.

Answer (score 7):

He's using comparison to a sporting tactic; in essence, 'when your opponent is in difficulty, that's when you hit hardest'

Although all of the terms he used could probably be found in a dictionary, the meaning of them all in combination is probably considerably harder, so let me run through it...

- A pugilist is a boxer, it comes from the Latin for fist.
- 'worth his salt' - that's generally used to define someone who is good enough at his job to be fully worth the salary he gets.
  The word 'salary' even comes from the Latin for salt, which it's generally believed is how Roman soldiers were paid. [That's apparently untrue, but the belief led to the modern term anyway.]
- In a boxing match, the general idea seems to be to stay away from the edges - the ropes round the ring - in order to have better freedom of movement.
  To be "up against the ropes" is to be in difficulty. This phrase has long  been borrowed for similar situations unrelated to boxing.
- The rest deals with actual punching methods. A combination of two punches, guaranteed to win the fight.
  Essentially - punch him in the stomach, then punch him in the face.

A more common usage would be the much shorter "hit him when he's down" - which is considered unfair & unsporting... but of course, that's Underwood through & through.

Answer (score 0):

"Pugilist" = boxer, basically.  So he's talking about the sport of boxing.

"On the ropes" - this doesn't just refer to someone's positioning, it refers to when someone has been badly dazed or hurt by a punch or punches. They try to back away and escape the onslaught, and wind up with their backs against the ropes that define the boundaries of the ring, sometimes even leaning on them for support to keep from falling down.

"Worth his salt" - the origins are noted by Tesujin.  Basically, anyone who has any moderate or above skill or expertise would be "worth his salt."

"Combination" - in the boxing context, pretty straightforward - a series of punches thrown in rapid succession, instead of single punches.  Often, when thrown in combination, punches, even if blocked or defended, serve to expose gaps in the defense for subsequent punches to land more cleanly.

"Hook" - that is a punch that is thrown where the path of the punch follows a looping path, first wide and then moving towards the center, essentially coming in from the side.  Given the wider arc and distance traveled, there is a lot of potential for greater power being generated as well.  The punch is especially effective in getting around defense that are set up to block incoming punches that come straight in from the attacker.

To put it all together, when someone gets stunned or hurt in boxing, quite often they're unable to think clearly, and instincts take over.  This includes trying to back away from the fighter, and, also, they often raise their hands up to their head to try and prevent any more blows from landing, trying to get time to regain control of their senses and recover.

So if a fighter backs into the ropes, covering his head, hard punches to the body, initially, will hurt the fighter, and often they will lower their hands to protect their torso, which would open up the defense, leaving the head open for the subsequent punches, with the hook also having the advantage of going around hands being held up in front of the head.  That combination is a standard sequence for finishing/knocking out a fighter once they are hurt.